# What is Wrong with this

Tags: css, google-web-designer

[image]

what is Wrong  WIth this Code?? i have tried to color the span with red when the button is checked but that does't work with me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

For first `span`:

```
input:checked ~ span:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
input:checked ~ span:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="">Click
<br><span>mohammedSerwan</span>
<br><span>Mohammed2</span>
```

For all `span` so use `~`:

```
input:checked ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
input:checked ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="">Click
<br><span>mohammedSerwan</span>
<br><span>Mohammed2</span>
```